# Need to change javascript code

Tags: javascript

I made a pdf where user should fill all information and after that he will sign or atleast something will be there so that other can understand who already worked in the file. For this purpose adobe digital signature option is very good. But if I use this feature i have to save the pdf file each time it is signed. I want to avoid each time saving. So I searched google and found below code. This code is for livecycle designer. I do not know the formcalc language and I have also little knowledge in Javascript coding.

Could anyone be able to help me in using below code for my acrobat pro form?
Thanks

```
     form1.page1.Button1::mouseDown - (FormCalc, client)

var vDate = Num2Date(Date(), "DD-MMM-YYYY", "en_IE")

var vTime = Num2Time(Time(), "HH:MM:SS")

vSignTime = Concat(vDate, " at ", vTime)

 form1.page1.Button1::click - (JavaScript, client)

// associate the button with a particular signature field
var vSignatureField = signature01.name.toString(); 

// get time stamp in and SafeCode
var timeIn = signingForm.timeStamp();
var sLetter = signingForm.letter(); 
var sNumber = signingForm.number(); 
var SafeCode = sLetter + "-" + sNumber;

// call signing script
signingForm.sign(SafeCode);

// get time stamp out
var timeOut = signingForm.timeStamp(); 
//console.println("timestamp: " + timeOut);

// check time stamp
if (timeOut != timeIn)
{
    xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = "SafeCode sync failure: please apply signature again...";
}
else
{
    // check user credentials and sign if OK
    if (vUser.value == "" || vPass.value == "")
    {
        xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = "";
    }

    else 
    {
        if (vUser.value == User1.value && vPass.value == (SafeCode + Pass1.value))
        {
            xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = vUser.value + ", approved on " + vSignTime.value; 
        }
        else if (vUser.value == User2.value && vPass.value == (SafeCode + Pass2.value))
        {
            xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = vUser.value + ", approved on " + vSignTime.value; 
        }
        else if (vUser.value == User3.value && vPass.value == (SafeCode + Pass3.value))
        {
            xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = vUser.value + ", approved on " + vSignTime.value;
        }
        else 
        {
            xfa.resolveNode("form1.page1." + vSignatureField).rawValue = "Invalid signature, contact administration...";
        }
    }

}


 form1.page1.signature01::preSave - (JavaScript, client)

console.println("Password 1 before save is " + Pass1.value); 

Pass1.value = Pass1.value; 

console.println("Password 1 after save is " + Pass1.value);
```

Comment: if I work on a file I'd like to see my changes saved, no?

Comment: My problem is that if I use adobe digital signature feature each time save as window appears. I want to avoid this thing only.